# Django-project RuntimeError The asyncio event loop must not change after connection

Tags: django-views, python-asyncio

I have the code of my django project. There is a tgbot.py, which stores the send_to_telegram function. The program collects data from the db.sqlite3, converts it to .json and sends each record as a message to the list of channels specified in channels.json.
There is also a code in views.py , which has 2 functions: start_auto and stop_auto. After starting start_auto, the send_to_telegram function starts sending messages through channels, and when the stop_auto function is called, it stops its work.
The problem is that after calling the stop_auto function, I try to call start_auto again, but I get an error
`RuntimeError at /start/`
`The asyncio event loop must not change after connection.`

tgbot.py (send_to_ telegram)

```
async def send_to_telegram(stop_event):
    async with client:
        await client.connect()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM carparcapp_car")
        cars = []

        for row in cursor:
            cars.append({
                "Марка": row[1],
                "Тип": row[2],
                "Кабина": row[3],
                "Формула": row[4],
                "Двигатель": row[5],
                "Мощность": row[6],
                "КПП": row[7],
                "Мосты": row[8],
                "Евро-класс": row[9],
                "Фото": 'media/' + row[10]
            })

        with open('cars.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            json.dump(cars, outfile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

        conn.close()

        with open('cars.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            cars_list = json.load(file)

        with open('channels.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            channels = json.load(file)

        index = 0

        while not stop_event.is_set() and index < len(cars_list):
            for channel in channels:
                car = cars_list[index]
                try:
                    photo_path = car.get("Фото")
                    caption = ""
                    for key, value in car.items():
                        if key != "Фото":
                            caption += f"{key}: {value}\n"
                    with open(photo_path, 'rb') as photo_file:
                        await client.send_file(channel, photo_file, caption=caption)
                    sleep(10)
                except PermissionError:
                    caption = ""
                    for key, value in car.items():
                        if key != "Фото":
                            caption += f"{key}: {value}\n"
                    await client.send_message(channel, caption)
                    sleep(5)
                index += 1
                if index >= len(cars_list):
                    break
```

views.py

```
async def start_auto(request):
    global stop_event
    stop_event = Event()
    await send_to_telegram(stop_event)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def stop_auto(request):
    global stop_event
    stop_event.set()
    print('Программа остановлена!')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Please, help me with my django-project.